# How to display all suppliers in order detail?

Tags: smarty, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I want to display a list of ALL suppliers available in the order detail page in a select box and all suppliers available for that product in another select box.

What I tried to do is add to *\prestashop\admin\themes\default\template\controllers\orders\helpers\view\view.tpl*:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="id_supplier" class="control-label col-lg-3">{l s='Supplier'}</label>
    <div class="col-lg-9">
        <div class="col-lg-8">
            <select id="id_supplier" name="id_supplier">
                {foreach from=$suppliers item='supplier'}
                    <option value="{$supplier.id_supplier}">{$supplier.name}</option>
                {/foreach}
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

But this doesn't work (the select box is empty).

Comment: are you sure that there is availlable $suppliers smarty variable? put {debug} in template.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there's no `$supplier` in controllers/admin/AdminOrdersController.php which means that you need to get informations about Suppliers by using this code:

`$suppliers = Supplier::getSuppliers();`

of course you need to `foreach` this loop and check which supplier is already in order and create another array for second select

after that you need to assign those variables in `renderView` method in controller